# selenium testng xml classes running in parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and TestNG.
I would like my Test Classes to run sequentially, but they appear to run in parallel.
Thw worts, when the second is started both fail.
I would like TestScenario19 to run only when TestScenario3 ends execution.

Below is my testng.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Testing">
    <!--test verbose="1" name="FF Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="FF"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestSignInPage"></class>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestOpeningSearchPages"></class>
        </classes>
    </test-->
    <test verbose="1" name="Chrome Test - Search Page" parallel="none">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario3"></class>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario19"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How to run the second class only after the first ends?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below testng xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Testing" parallel="none">
    <test verbose="1" name="Chrome Test - Search Page">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario3"></class>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario19"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not posted in the better way, because I was not understanding it.
In my setup, I'm using the testng priority annotation in the methods, for them to run in a specific order. I thought that each class would run sequentially and for each class its methods would run in the specified order. 
So both classes have their methods with the priority annotation, and in both classes the method ordering starts with priority 1.....So when I run testng.xml file the methods will run by priority independently of the class to which they belong.
This is the explantion for the observed behaviour and the configuration of the parallel attribute does not have effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

just remove parallel attribute from your test tag

```
<test verbose="1" name="Chrome Test - Search Page" parallel="none">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario3"></class>
            <class name="nl.riskco.test.TestScenario19"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```